# Stacked Custom Progress

Tags: css

Due to my CSS normal bootstrap Stacked Progress bars wont work so I started making my own, but their stacking vertically not horizontal and I'm not sure how to fix that.

[image: Meter now]

This is my intention
[image: Meter now]

I have included the code that created the problem which is mainly css so i'm assuming its just CSS i need to fix it

```
<style>
.progress {
          margin:0;
          padding:0;
          background-color:salmon;
          -moz-border-radius-topleft: 12px; 
          -moz-border-radius-topright:12px; 
          -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:12px; 
          -moz-border-radius-bottomright:12px; 
          -webkit-border-top-left-radius:12px; 
          -webkit-border-top-right-radius:12px; 
          -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:12px;
          -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:12px;
          border-top-left-radius:12px; 
          border-top-right-radius:12px; 
          border-bottom-left-radius:12px;
          border-bottom-right-radius:12px;
          background: repeating-linear-gradient(
                      45deg,
                      crimson,
                      crimson 10px,
                      lightsalmon 10px,
                      lightsalmon 20px
          );/*background*/
          background-size: 200% 200%;
          animation: barberpole 2s linear infinite;
 }/*.progress*/
.progress-bar {
          margin:0;
          padding:0;
          text-align:left;
          padding-left:0.5em;
          font-size: small;
          height: 1.4em;
          -moz-border-radius-topleft: 12px; 
          -moz-border-radius-topright:12px; 
          -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:12px; 
          -moz-border-radius-bottomright:12px; 
          -webkit-border-top-left-radius:12px; 
          -webkit-border-top-right-radius:12px; 
          -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:12px;
          -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:12px;
          border-top-left-radius:12px; 
          border-top-right-radius:12px; 
          border-bottom-left-radius:12px;
          border-bottom-right-radius:12px;
 }/*.progress-bar*/
.progress-bar-success {
          -moz-border-radius-topleft: 12px; 
          -moz-border-radius-topright:12px; 
          -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:12px; 
          -moz-border-radius-bottomright:12px; 
          -webkit-border-top-left-radius:12px; 
          -webkit-border-top-right-radius:12px; 
          -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:12px;
          -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:12px;
          border-top-left-radius:12px; 
          border-top-right-radius:12px; 
          border-bottom-left-radius:12px;
          border-bottom-right-radius:12px;
          background: repeating-linear-gradient(
                      45deg,
                      springgreen,
                      springgreen 10px,
                      limegreen 10px,
                      limegreen 20px
          );/*background*/
          background-size: 200% 200%;
          animation: barberpole 2s linear infinite;
 }/*.progress-bar-success*/
.progress-bar-info {
          -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px; 
          -moz-border-radius-topright:12px; 
          -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px; 
          -moz-border-radius-bottomright:12px; 
          -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px; 
          -webkit-border-top-right-radius:12px; 
          -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
          -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:12px;
          border-top-left-radius:0px; 
          border-top-right-radius:12px; 
          border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
          border-bottom-right-radius:12px;
          background: repeating-linear-gradient(
                      45deg,
                      cornflowerblue,
                      cornflowerblue 10px,
                      lavender 10px,
                      lavender 20px
          );/*background*/
          background-size: 200% 200%;
          animation: barberpole 2s linear infinite;
 }/*.progress-bar-info*/
@keyframes barberpole {
  100% {background-position: 100% 100%;}
}/*@keyframes barberpole*/
.desc {
          margin:0;
          padding:0;
          text-align:left;
          padding-left:0.5em;
          padding-bottom:0.5em;
          font-size: xx-small;
          font-weight:normal;
 }/*.desc*/
 </style>
      <!---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
      <hr style="width:100%; margin:0; margin-bottom:1em; margin-top: 1em; padding:0" />
      <!-- Cooking -->
      <div class="progress" style="text-align:left;">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:25%;">
        <img src="../images/cooking-icon.png" style="width: 1.3em; padding-bottom:0.45em" />: 5<b class="desc">(Cooking)</b>
        </div><!-- progress-bar-success / Green -->

        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" style="width:14%;">
        <i class="fas fa-tint"></i>: 6
        </div><!-- progress-bar-info / Blue -->

      </div><!-- <div class="progress"> -->
```

Comment: The default `display` value of a `div` is `block` which is why your `.progress-bar` are stacking.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render the nested bars in one line, you can just add `display: flex` to the CSS properties of the parent line (salmon color).

Or, if you want the nested bars overlapping each other, you should set the parent size width to 100%, use a static height (in your case, 18px), and position your nested lines absolutely:

```
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: flex was it, the text is still breaking to the next line, is there a way to force it to be inline with the div?

Comment: Just add display:flex to each child line. And if you want to center text inside bar just use  align-items: center
Complete code: .child_bar {display: flex; align-items: center;}